# How to change the icon of %windir% on win 7

Tags: windows-7, icons

Win 7 have `Customize` tab in folder right click context menu for most directory but `C:\Windows` as an exception.
Anyone knows how to customize the icon of `%windir%` (usually `C:\windows`)?

BTW, I mean doing this as a user, but not doing this programmatically.

Comment: This might be a better question for superuser.  Are you trying to do this programmatically?

Comment: [**Here's how you can change the icon.**](http://bit.ly/UlNs4s)

Comment: @patrickmjones no, I'm try to do this as a user via GUI/console

Comment: @attronics C:\Windows is an exception, you troll

Answer (score 0):

Folder icon overrides are specified in a `desktop.ini` file in that folder.

Just copy that file from another folder.

Comment: Hi Slaks, I tried, but it do not work, the windows icon becomes a blank fold when I copied a `desktop.ini` to C:\windows, even after a restart. The content of it (no multi-line in comment, so \n stands for a newline): 
    `[.ShellClassInfo]\n
    IconResource=D:\ico\Token\System+Settings\Gear.ico,0\n
    IconIndex=0`